# React Fullstack app showing error with mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb, reactjs

I created a simple CRUD Application using the MERN stack. This app was working fine yesterday but today when I made some changes to the frontend, and started to run the app, it is not working and throwing error related to the mongodb connection. I can provide all my frontend code too(but its showing no error when running the frontend). Here is the error I get when doing npm start on my backend project:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server is running on Port:  4200
App starting error: MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/afzaal/expressbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:328:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/afzaal/expressbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:274:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/afzaal/expressbackend/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:177:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var port = 4200;
var cors = require('cors');

// Mongoose connection with mongodb
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/data')//what should I put for the URI?
    .then(() => { // if all is ok we will be here
      console.log('Start');
    })
    .catch(err => { // if error we will be here
        console.error('App starting error:', err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });

// Required application specific custom router module
var itemRouter = require('./src/routes/itemRoutes');

// Use middlewares to set view engine and post json data to the server
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/items', itemRouter);

// Start the server
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server is running on Port: ',port);
});
```

I do have mongodb installed. I am pretty new to mongodb so Im not sure whats going on with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have it running? Tried running `mongo` from terminal?

Comment: i typed mongo in the terminal root directory. it says failed to connect to port 27017. How to connect it?

Comment: windows or ubuntu ??? mongoose version and mongodb version ???

Comment: i am using mac. i have mongodb installed. mongo version is 3.0.5

Comment: *"mongo version is 3.0.5"* - That actually sounds like the "node driver version" and not the installed MongoDB "server". When you say "installed" you mean by `npm install mongodb` or simply `npm install` for the version specified in `package.json` right? Because that is not the "server". You need to install a server to connect to.

Comment: See [Install MongoDB Community Edition on macOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)